# View all ratings and reviews in iTunes for PC

Tags: itunes

I have iTunes installed on my Windows 10 PC. I have written reviews for some podcasts and albums.

I can see my own reviews if I look up the specific podcast and album and go to the Ratings & Reviews section. However, is there a way, maybe within the account menu, to check all my ratings & reviews in one place?

Answer (score 1):

I am demonstrating the steps using iTunes for macOS. They should be similar for iTunes for Windows.

Make sure you are logged in with your Apple ID in iTunes. Access your account from within the Podcasts Store.

[image]

On your **Account Information** page, under **Settings** section you can find **Reviews and Ratings** section. Click on **Manage** link in front of it to view all your reviews and ratings in one place.

[image]

Comment: I see the difference here. In Windows the only entry under Settings is Personalized Recommendations. The lines Nickname, Reviews and Ratings, and Alert Me are not present.